# trouble with linear regression plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression

hi so im trying to use the reg.fit function to plot a graph of the co2 emitted from a diet. the code runs ok but the graph that is plotted shows all of the y values bunched up at the right side of the graph so I think theres an issue with the way the x values are being passed.

this is my code

```
data = pd.read_csv("food.csv")
plt.figure(figsize=[15, 10])

plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=3)

imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value=0)

x= data['Date'].values
x = pd.to_datetime(x, errors="coerce")
print(x)
x = x.values.astype("float64").reshape(-1,1)
                     
y = data['TOTAL'].values
imputer = imp_mean.fit([y])
y = imputer.transform([y])
print(y)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)

print(f"The slope is {reg.coef_[0][0]} and the intercept is 
  {reg.intercept_[0]}")

predictions = reg.predict(x)
                      
plt.scatter(x, y,c='black')
plt.plot(x, predictions, c='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.title("CO2eq emitted from diet")
plt.ylabel('CO2eq');
plt.xlabel('Date');
plt.show()
```

this is the graph
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAFuK.jpg

the csv file is structured like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnVK.jpg

Comment: Have you tried printing `y`? Does it match the graph?

Comment: @DYZ yeah the y values seem to be correct, its just the x values. I have a suspicion it has something to do with the conversion of date to float.

Comment: My bad. I actually wanted to ask you to print `x`.

Comment: @DYZ so x is printing values [ 1.64609280e+18]
 [ 1.64617920e+18]
 [ 1.64626560e+18]
 [ 1.64635200e+18]
 [ 1.64643840e+18]

Comment: @DYZ i think this is because im converting the datetime to a float through x.values.astype("float64") but im not sure what the correct practice is

Comment: Just use the original x values from the dataframe, prior to the conversions.

Comment: @DYZ ok that has worked but now the prediction line has an issue heres what its looking like https://imgur.com/a/Lf24rCR

Comment: There must be some problem with your data. Note that the last point of the training set is an obvious outlier.